# Is there any option available in GitHub to push workflow logs to database?

Tags: github, logging, github-actions, github-api

Is there any option available in GitHub to push workflow logs to database ?

Any third party REST API or CLI based extensions/tasks readily available to push build logs to DBMS ?

Any third party REST API or CLI based extensions/tasks readily available to push build logs to cloud storage ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking https://github.com/shahargl/upload-github-workflow-logs-to-elastic, see https://anecdotes.dev/integrating-github-actions-logs-to-your-elasticsearch-306a81738106 for details.
"In this blog post, I’ll guide you through how to sync your GitHub Actions workflow logs into Elasticsearch. .... I developed a GitHub Action that will do it for you."

Comment: Thank you, but i am looking for options(readily available tasks) to push the logs as file or blob to the storage. At this point, i am not looking for search engine/Elasticsearch option.

Comment: If so I suggest you edit your question.
I'm using these 2 lines for archive logs and copy tarball to GCP cloud bucket:

tar  --warning=no-file-changed  -czf /tmp/${FILENAME}-runner-logs.tgz ~/actions-runner/_diag/ || true
gsutil cp /tmp/${FILENAME}-runner-logs.tgz gs://${GS_BUCKET_NAME}